# Erlang TCP server handling

Tags: tcp, erlang

I am starting to learn Erlang in the hopes of creating a game server to real-time multiplayer games. Currently, I am trying to estimate the amount of work and headache Erlang would cause vs. Scala. So, to start, I am creating a simple Erlang server process. I found a nice tutorial by [Jesse Farmer](http://20bits.com/article/network-programming-in-erlang/) which I have modified to learn more.  My modified code is meant to be similar to his echo server, except it takes in English words and simply returns the Lojban equivalent.  However, only the wildcard case is ever selected.  Here is the code:

```
-module(translate).
-export([listen/1]).
-import(string).

-define(TCP_OPTIONS, [binary, {packet, 0}, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}]).

% Call echo:listen(Port) to start the service.
listen(Port) ->
    {ok, LSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, ?TCP_OPTIONS),
    accept(LSocket).

% Wait for incoming connections and spawn the echo loop when we get one.
accept(LSocket) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(LSocket),
    spawn(fun() -> loop(Socket) end),
    accept(LSocket).

% Echo back whatever data we receive on Socket.
loop(Socket) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            case Data of
                "Hello" -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "coi\n");
                "Hello\n" -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "coi\n");
                'Hello' -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "coi\n");
                <<"Hello">> -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "coi\n");
                <<"Hello\n">> -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "coi\n");
                _ -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "I don't understand")
            end,
            loop(Socket);
        {error, closed} ->
            ok
    end.
```

My current test is to open two terminal windows and execute

```
[CONSOLE 1]
erl
c(translate).
translate:listen(8888).

[CONSOLE 2]
telnet localhost 8888
whatever
Hello
```

And the output becomes:

```
I don't understand
I don't understand
```

How can I parse the incoming data?  This style of pattern matching seems to be failing completely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
case binary_to_list(Data) of
    "Hello\r\n" -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "this will be good variant\n");
    _ -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "I don't understand")
end,
```

Or without explicit convert:

```
case Data of
    <<"Hello\r\n">> -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "this will be good variant\n");
    _ -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "I don't understand")
end,
```

**Updated from comments**

To work with more complicated matching remove `"\r\n"` suffix first:

```
Content = list_to_binary(lists:subtract(binary_to_list(Data), "\r\n")),
case Content of
    <<"Hello">> -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, <<"Good day!\n">>);
    <<"My name is, ", Name/binary>> -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, <<"Hello ", Name/binary, "!\n">>);
    _ -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "I don't understand")
end,
```

Comment: Phenomenal! That seems to work great. Following this, how would I pull pieces of information out of the incoming packet?  I tried something like `<<"My name is ", Name, "\r\n">> -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, "Hello " ++ Name ++ "!\n")`, but it never hits this case either.

Comment: @Grimless Two errors: 1. The right way to match `Name` here: `<<"My name is ", Name:10/binary, "\r\n">>` where `10` is `Name` length (you should specify length in any case for non-rest matching). I know, that this is not you actually want :) so try to split `Data` first (in those way that `Name` will the last part of binary). 2. `"Hello " ++ Name ++ "!\n"` will fail. This not: `<<"Hello ", Name/binary, "!\n">>` (or if you want to work with lists `"Hello " ++ binary_to_list(Name) ++ "!\n"` - but too many actions for simple operation).

Comment: Hmm, the `"Hello " ++ Name ++ "!\n"` seems to compile just fine, but it is likely not causing an issue because that clause is never executed.  How would I go about 'splitting `Data` first'?  I can't guarantee the length of the input name, so how does `Name:10/binary` handle input such as `The Duke of All The World`? Also, changing the code to `<<"My name is ", Name:10/binary, "\r\n">> -> gen_tcp:send(Socket, string:join(["mi'o ", Name, "\r\n"], ""));` still does not function.

Comment: Excellent! While Erlang feels very clunky and old at this time, I recognize the ideas and paradigms it presents are very elegant. Thank you for your help!